# ejecutar consulta mysql PHP

Tags: php

Estoy intentando ejecutar una consulta y que me muestre los datos.

```
<?php 
    $sql = "SELECT nombre FROM canciones WHERE idartistas = '$idartistas' ";                 
?>
```

tengo eso hecho en php y para mostrar los datos hago lo siguente;

```
<p align="left">
  <?php print $sql?>
</p>
```

Cuando abro la página me muestra la consulta y no los datos de la consulta.

He cambiado y puesto esto pero ahora me da este fallo:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\PaginaWebPBLlocal\todoartista.php on line 88
>
> Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\PaginaWebPBLlocal\todoartista.php on line 88 Consulta
>   fallida:

```
    $conexion = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "discografica");
        if ($conexion->connect_errno) {
    echo "Fallo al conectar a MySQL: (" . $conexion->connect_errno . ") " . $conexion->connect_error;
}
    $query = "SELECT nombre FROM canciones WHERE idartistas = '$idartistas' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($query) or die('Consulta fallida: ' . mysqli_error());

?>
```

Comment: Tal y como está es simplemente una cadena, para ejecutarla hay muchas formas y al menos dos drivers recomendados _(Mysqli, PDO)_ , Pero podría empezar [por aquí hay ejemplos de como hacer un select por ejemplo](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php) teniendo en consideración preparar sus querys.

Comment: Como bien dice el error, la funcion [mysqli_query](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) espera 2 parametros (Conexion y Consulta, respectivamente) y se le dio uno (la Consulta, solamente) y ademas [mysqli_error](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error.php) espera 1 parametro (Conexion) y no se le dio ninguno. (Cuando leas los links, vé el "Estilo orientado a procedimientos" que es el que estas usando). Por otro lado te aconsejo leer [como evitar la inyeccion sql en php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php).

Answer (score 0):

Lo que estas haciendo ahí es crear una simple variable llamada sql con el valor en cadena:

```
SELECT nombre FROM canciones WHERE idartistas = '$idartistas'
```

Para conexión a bases de datos necesitas otros objetos de **PHP** que te permitan ejecutar las consultas, te puedes guiar de este ejemplo para conexión con MYSQL: http://php.net/manual/es/mysql.examples-basic.php

Comment: en mi pregunta añadi el codigo nuevo que puse ,pero que tampoco funcion

Comment: Pasa como parametro tu conexion al metodo **mysqli_query()**:                                                                                                                                      
 `$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $query) or die('Consulta fallida: ' . mysqli_error());`

Answer (score 0):

El error al momento de realizar la consulta y obtener el resultado es debido a que sólo le estas pasando 1 parámetro a `mysqli_query`:

```
$result = mysqli_query($query) or die('Consulta fallida: ' . mysqli_error());
```

**La sintaxis correcta de `mysqli_query` es esta :**  `$resultado($conexionABaseDeDatos, $query, MODO_DEL_RESULTADO);`

*(La constante del modo de resultado puede ser `MYSQLI_USE_RESULT` ó `MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT`  dependiendo de tus necesidades)*.

El segundo error es debido a que `mysqli_error()` requiere de la conexión a la base de datos como parámetro: `mysqli_error($conexionDB)`

**De modo que la manera correcta para obtener tu resultado sería la siguiente**:

```
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $query, MYSQLI_USE_RESULT) or die('Consulta fallida: ' . mysqli_error($conexion));
```

Después de esto la variable **$resultado** será igual a los datos de la conssulta, de esta manera ya podrás imprimir lo que esta contiene.

Espero que haya sido de tu ayuda :)